# Linq GroupBy throws an exception in .NET 6

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework-core

I had the following query running successfully in old .NET framework 4.7.2 project, but the following query breaks in .NET 6 in migrated project

```
var query = from x in dbContext.table1 
            join y in dbContext.table2 
                   on x.AccountId equals y.AccountId
            join dbContext.v on x.RecId = v.RecId
            group new 
                  {
                      x,
                      y.Name,
                      y.Email,
                      v.SecretKey
                  }
            by new 
               {
                   x.CreatedDate,
                   y.Name   
               }     
            into grp
            orderby grp.Key.Name,
            select grp;
```

It throws this error:

> OrderBy(grp => grp.Key.Name)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.'

And I can't use `ToList()` on just the join because on production there are millions of records in database which cannot be fetched each time in client side to apply group by operation.

How can I restructure the query to get it to work in .NET 6 ?

**Note**: the variable name taken as example as it is not possible to post company code here

Comment: This is the key  `new { x.SomeSelector,  y.SomeSelector1 } ` Obviously it does not contain a property called `Name` and the query translations fails.

Comment: @AntonKovachev ive fixed the description of the question , actually i was making example from our code so missed to put the selector name properly , ive corrected it , can u now see and suggest something ?

Comment: EF core has far less GroupBy support than EF6. Since you don't aggregate anything it doesn't cost more to get the data you need by a simple query and do the grouping client-side (in memory).

Comment: @GertArnold there are million records on production db and in example i just put only 2-3 columns to fetch but in actual query there are more than 10 columns fetched and this query is inside such a method in web api controller that has more hits each second than anything

Comment: So get the data (columns) you need and do the grouping in memory. As I said, it's the same amount of data because you don't aggregate.